# CompletableFuture callback not called if completed manually

Tags: java, completable-future

In this basic example of **CompletableFuture**, I run a task asynchronously and when it's finished, an async callback should be triggered.

One second after I start running the task, and before it's finished, I complete it. After that I don't see it running the asynchronous callback anymore.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    runTask();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    completableFuture.complete("Test");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
}

public static void runTask() {
    completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("Running...");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("...finished");
        return "finished task";
    })
    .thenApplyAsync(s -> {
        System.out.println("Apply on result: " + s);
        return "Result: " + s;
    })
}
```

The result of this is:

```
Running...
...finished
```

The thing is that if I add another callback, then it runs the first one but not the second one.

```
.thenApplyAsync(s -> {
    System.out.println("Second apply with result: " + s);
    return "Result: " + s;
})
```

Then the result is:

```
Running...
...finished
Apply on result: finished task
```

Reading the documentation I understood all the callbacks would be always called, even if the future is completed manually. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The problem is likely that in `runTask()` you are not assigning the future returning `"finished task"`, but the future returning `"Result: "`, which you are then completing manually. Therefore when the original future is finished, the next stage is already completed (manually by you), so it is probably not run.

Comment: Bu then why does it run it if I add an extra callback after the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess if you write it slightly differently, it should make some sense:

```
public static void runTask() {

    CompletableFuture<String> one = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("Running...");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("...finished");
        return "finished task";
    });

    CompletableFuture<String> two = one.thenApplyAsync(s -> {
        System.out.println("Apply on result: " + s);
        return "Result: " + s;
    });

    completableFuture = two;
}
```

So, `one` in your case starts just fine, but before `two` can even start, you issue `completableFuture.complete("Test");`. So when `one` is done, there is nothing for it to `thenApplyAsync`, since that one is already completed.

When you add one more stage, you basically get:

```
....
CompletableFuture<String> two = one.thenApplyAsync(s -> {
     System.out.println("Apply on result: " + s);
     return "Result: " + s;
});

CompletableFuture<String> three = two.thenApplyAsync(s -> {
     System.out.println("Second apply with result: " + s);
     return "Result: " + s;
});

completableFuture = three;
```

You can probably see what happens here, without even me explaining.

---

To that end, I can't see where the documentation would make this clear though. I guess we somehow need to see that in [package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), via:

> When two or more threads attempt to complete, completeExceptionally, or cancel a CompletableFuture, only one of them succeeds.

This somehow implies that if a certain stage is not yet started, but someone else, externally `complete`s it; that stage will not run at all. This makes sense, but the package documentation could be more clear, imo.

Comment: When I add callbacks to the completable, it runs all of them except the last one, and I'm certain that I complete it manually before it the execution is finished. This happens no matter how many callbacks there are, all of them are executed but the last one.
In case there's only one callback, then nothing is run.

Comment: @mpcx sorry, but did u read this answer? The "last" one is completed, by you, by calling `complete(Test)` in the main thread. So by the time it is supposed to run, it is already completed and there is nothing to do there.